# How do we return function using module.exports in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do we return function using module.exports in nodeJS?

**file_1 book.js**

```
  module.exports = function() {
    var points = 0;
    return {
        rate: function(value) {
            points = value;
        },
        get: function() {
            return points;
        }
    }
}
```

book.js is root file. We create two different instances but can not get the methods of root to script.js file.

**file_2 main.js**

```
  var bA = require('./book.js');
  var bB = require('./book.js');
  bB.rate(10);
  bB.get();
```

**Output => `can not find rate and get method.`**

Comment: Try `require('./book.js')()` since you have to actually execute the exported object.

Answer (score 8):

Because the function returns an object with references to the `rate` and `get` functions, you need to execute it with a `()` on require like so:

```
  var book = require('./book.js')();
  book.rate(10);
  book.get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a function which returns an object.

Call the function and get the object

```
  /*file_2 main.js*/
  var bA = require('./book.js')();
  var bB = require('./book.js')();
  bB.rate(10);
  bB.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone's facing same problem as me
I had something issue with my code. Lately realised I was making some API call and so return returned an object before fetching the value from API endpoint

I added async in front of function call and it worked!

```
var util=require('./app/Utils')

const url=await util.getInfo();
```

Answer (score -1):

***You can also provide a name to your anonymous export function as***

```
module.exports.myfun = function() {
var points = 0;
return {
    rate: function(value) {
        points = value;
    },
    get: function() {
        return points;
    }
} }
```

***Then use the function in another file as***

```
var inc = require('./comp.js');
var mod = inc.myfun();
mod.rate(10);
console.log(mod.get());
```

***In this way you don't need to have '()' at the time of required, though that option can also be used***